# Using dimensionality reduction on matrix

Tags: python, machine-learning, pca, dimensionality-reduction

For supervised learning, my matrix size is really huge as a result of which only certain models agree to run with it. I read that PCA can help reducing dimensionality to a large extent.

Below is my code:

```
def run(command):
    output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
    return output

f = open('/Users/ya/Documents/10percent/Vik.txt','r')
vocab_temp = f.read().split()
f.close()
col = len(vocab_temp)
print("Training column size:")
print(col)

#dataset = list()

row = run('cat '+'/Users/ya/Documents/10percent/X_true.txt'+" | wc -l").split()[0]
print("Training row size:")
print(row)
matrix_tmp = np.zeros((int(row),col), dtype=np.int64)
print("Train Matrix size:")
print(matrix_tmp.size)
        # label_tmp.ndim must be equal to 1
label_tmp = np.zeros((int(row)), dtype=np.int64)
f = open('/Users/ya/Documents/10percent/X_true.txt','r')
count = 0
for line in f:
    line_tmp = line.split()
    #print(line_tmp)
    for word in line_tmp[0:]:
        if word not in vocab_temp:
            continue
        matrix_tmp[count][vocab_temp.index(word)] = 1
    count = count + 1
f.close()
print("Train matrix is:\n ")
print(matrix_tmp)
print(label_tmp)
print(len(label_tmp))
print("No. of topics in train:")
print(len(set(label_tmp)))
print("Train Label size:")
print(len(label_tmp))
```

I wish to apply PCA to matrix_tmp as it has a size of about (202180x9984). How can I modify my code to include it?

Answer (score 1):

```
import codecs
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
with codecs.open('input_file', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as inf:
    lines = inf.readlines()
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(binary=True)
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(lines)
perform_pca = False
if perform_pca:
    n_components = 100
    pca = TruncatedSVD(n_components)
    X_train = pca.fit_transform(X_train)
```

1- Do the vectorization with available verctorizers in sklearn which produces sparse matrices instead of a full matrix with massive zero values.

2- Do the PCA only if needed

3- For performance play with the parameters of your vectorizer and pca if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Scikit-learn provides several PCA implementations. One useful one is `TruncatedSVD`. Its usage is fairly straightforward:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD

n_components=100
pca = TruncatedSVD(n_components)
matrix_reduced = pca.fit_transform(matrix_tmp)
```

Comment: Hi, when I try adding these lines to my code, the entire program hangs and stops responding. Is my matrix size too huge to handle for dimensionality reduction?

Comment: That could be. Looking at your code, you may be better off with a sparse (csr) matrix than a dense numpy matrix. Scikit-learn provides a vectorizer `CountVectorizer` for building sparse matrices from text input. Also, you may want to subsample rows.